# PCF on Azure: 404 error when cf login -a api.system-domain

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcf, pcfdev

Installed PCF small footprint on Azure, but the post-deploy errand of 'push-apps-manager' failed on:

> Setting api endpoint to https://api.SYSTEM_DOMAIN_NAME.
>   API endpoint not found at 'https://api.SYSTEM_DOMAIN_NAME'

If I run:

```
cf login -a https://api.SYSTEM_DOMAIN_NAME -u admin --skip-ssl-validation
```

I got:

> FAILED
>   Server error, status code: 404, error code: 0, message:

Comment: Try to access the API url in a browser and see if it is really accessible

Comment: No, I can't access it in a browser either.  But if I check with bosh, I know the VM is up and running and I can ssh to the 'control' vm.

Comment: Probably you need to set proxy?